# How can I create a non-executable JAR with dependencies using Maven?

Tags: java, maven, jar, dependencies

I want to package my project in a single **non-executable** library JAR for distribution.
How can I make a Maven project package all dependency JARs into my output JAR?
There is a `jar-with-dependencies` option in Maven assembly plugin to create an **executable** JAR with dependencies. There is a [reciept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven) to obtain the goal. However, I need to build a library jar without `Main` class. How can I build such a jar?

Comment: Just build it and don't use the `maven-jar-plugin` per default it builds a non-executable `.jar` file. When the packaging is `jar`

Comment: There is a maven shade plugin, I believe that is what you are looking for. It will repack your dependencies directly into your jar. But I obviously have no idea why would you need it like that

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary that you use the maven-jar-plugin to build a non-executable jar. The `mvn clean install` command by default builds a non-executable jar if it has the node `<packaging>jar</packaging>` in your projects pom.xml.

Comment: Actually, this is a way to build a non-executable jar __without__ dependencies

Comment: Thanks for the correction.
Hope the maven-shade plugin helps you create a jar with dependencies. But not sure if it can be done without a Main class.